# Is it bad to have helper class that creates entity

Tags: php

Is it a bad practice to have a generic helper class that creates and hydrates entity object?
Example:

```
class EntityHelper {
    public static function createEntity($entityName, array $entityData, EntityManager $em) {
        $entity = new $entityName;
        $entityFields = $em->getClassMetadata($entityName)->getFieldNames();
       foreach ($entityFields as $field) {
            if (in_array($field, array_keys($entityData))) {
                $entity->{'set' . ucfirst($field)}($entityData[$field]);
            }   
        }
        return $entity;
    }
}
```

If it is a bad practice could anyone please suggest a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you are trying to do there (and the most important : why), but you can take a look at the IoC pattern

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control

[Understanding IoC Containers and Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562752/understanding-ioc-containers-and-dependency-injection)

Maybe a better way to create object of the correct type when you need it.

Thanks