# Is this a valid usage of the Factory pattern? multiple dependencies

Tags: php, unit-testing, design-patterns, phpunit, tdd

I want to create a set of dependencies instead of injecting them everywhere. Would the factory pattern support this idea? Or is there another pattern for dealing with it?

For example:

```
class PassportCheckFactory {
    protected $clientInstance;
    protected $responseInstance;

    public function buildDependancies() : bool
    {
        $this->clientInstance       = new PassportCheckSoapClient;
        $this->responseInstance    = new PassportCheckResponse;

        return true;
    }

    public function getResponseInstance()
    {
        return $this->responseInstance;
    }

    public function getClientInstance()
    {
        return $this->clientInstance;
    }
}
```

This creates  and holds the classes we would use, so we wouldn't need to inject them.

For example, we can do this

```
$request = new WhateverRequestClass;
$factory = (new PassportCheckFactory)->buildDependancies();
$service = new PassportCheckService($request, $factory);
$response = $service->execute();
```

instead of:

```
$request = new WhateverRequestClass;
$service = new PassportCheckService($request, new PassportCheckSoapClient, new PassportCheckResponse);
$response = $service->execute();
```

Comment: I would recommend going with the last example (the _"instead of"_) since that's proper dependency injection. It will also be much easier to test (passing mock objects etc.). In your other examples, you've basically turned your factory class into a service locator. Your factory will also instantiate all classes regardless if you need them for that request or not.

Comment: I would also recommend that you look into some IoC container that can make your code cleaner and easier to manage, like Pimple, Illuminate\Container or similar. Here's a stackoverflow post talking about dependency injection and containers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562752/understanding-ioc-containers-and-dependency-injection

Comment: thanks @MagnusEriksson 

If I use an IoC container, would that tightly couple my code to that container code. Lets say I needed to use the feature inside a legacy codebase, where the requirements don't support the container, I'd be stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach makes sense, if you want to support multiple CheckServices.
If `PassportCheckService` is the only one, the factory / service locator / specialised container from your example is just adding overhead.

```
$request = new WhateverRequestClass;
$service = new PassportCheckService($request, new PassportCheckSoapClient, new PassportCheckResponse);
$response = $service->execute();
```

is actually the best solution for a stand-alone service in terms of readability, maintainability and testabilty.

### Multiple CheckServices

However, if you want to support multiple services, extracting the composition of the service into its own class brings benefits.

```
class CheckServiceFactory
{
    public static function getService(Request $request, string $serviceType): CheckService
    {
        $type = ucfirst(strtolower($serviceType));

        $serviceClass  = $type . "CheckService";
        $clientClass   = $type . "CheckSoapClient";
        $responseClass = $type . "CheckResponse";

        return new $serviceClass($request, new $clientClass, new $responseClass);
    }
}
```

Of course, the generation of the classnames depends on your naming scheme.

Calling a specific service would look like this:

```
$request = new WhateverRequestClass;
$service = CheckServiceFactory::getService($request, 'Passport');
$response = $service->execute();
```

### Proposed Refactoring

Beside of the things above, I'd recommend to refactor the service class itself, so the request gets out of the constructor. That changes the usage 
to:

```
$request = new WhateverRequestClass;
$service = CheckServiceFactory::getService('Passport');
$response = $service->handle($request);
```

or in case of a single service:

```
$request = new WhateverRequestClass;
$service = new PassportCheckService(new PassportCheckSoapClient, new PassportCheckResponse);
$response = $service->handle($request);
```

which actually looks much more straight forward.

Comment: superb stuff, I owe you a beer! Do you think for testing the service class, I could simply bypass the factory (since its static) and create the service with a mocked client injected?

Comment: I made the factory static for shortness sake. It is better to keep it nonstatic. But you could create a 'PassportTest' service, which is built by the same factory.