# php object instantiation with variable after it, such as the type seen in Laravel?

Tags: php

I see and use this syntax alot in Laravel, I wonder how it works, cause I try to integrate it in my own project but I get errors like this

```
FATAL ERROR Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to getVal() must be an instance of Man, none given, called in'
```

now here is Laravel type code as you all know

```
public function join(Request $request){
    echo $request['name'];
    //for instance
}
```

and it works fine, now here is my code:

```
class Man {
    public $child,
           $wife;

   public function _construct(){
       $this->child = 1;
       $this->wife = 2;
   }
}

function getVal(Man $man){
    echo $man->wife;
}

getVal();
```

Please help me understand this better.

Comment: I know it would work that way, I'm just curious how it's done this way in Laravel

Comment: Not really about specifics man, all i'm asking is, it works in Laravel, how does it work?

Comment: That is totally pure PHP... You call `getVal();` without pass any `Argument` as you define

Comment: Are you asking about `automatic injection`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#automatic-injection. There is a lot of code behind the scenes that makes this work. It will not work automagically for you.

Comment: Also notice it is `__construct()` not `_construct()`.

Comment: I wouldn't know if thats the name, but from the link you provided I think that's what it is @waterloomatt

Comment: Thanks @waterloomatt, I think people should really understand a question before voting it down

Comment: It sounds like you want to know about how Laravel implements a `dependency injection container`. That is a large topic and I suggest you alter your question to make it a bit more specific. Here are a few links - https://stackoverflow.com/q/18562752/296555, http://php-di.org/ (never used this DI tool before but heard good things about it).

Comment: Thanks I appreciate

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, the value passed to `getVal()` must be an instance of `Man`, so your last line of `getVal()` needs to have an instance of `Man` passed to it.

It can be any instance of man, or itself:

`$man = new Man();
getVal($man)`

would also work

as would:

`$man = new Man();
$man2 = new Man();
getVal($man2)`

This is a normal way of writing PHP code.

However, there may be something else going on in Laravel, if you could link the location in the source code, that'd be great.

Comment: I know how to instantiate an object, I asked this question, because I see this stuff in Laravel where you are calling a method and then parameters are passed in such manner as I have written

Comment: @samezedi that's a normal way of writing code, that parameters are passed into a function, which can be used. Can you link to where you see the phenomenon in Laravel?

Comment: here is one example, glad I could pick this in laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/request when you land on that page scroll down to read some of its documentation and you will see what I am talking about

Comment: @samezedi that link leads to a 404

Answer (score 1):

Possibly wrong, but its piece of code, that could help you to find direction. Its not working, dunno how to return back to normal code.

```
<?php
set_exception_handler('myExcHandler');

function myExcHandler(Throwable $exception) {

    $fr = new ReflectionFunction($exception->getTrace()[0]['function']);

    $parameters = [];
    $st = new MyStaticClasses();

    foreach ($fr->getParameters() as $parameter) {
        $parameters[] = $st->getClass($parameter->name);
    }
    return call_user_func_array($exception->getTrace()[0]['function'], $parameters);
}

class Man {
    public $wife = 1;
}

class MyStaticClasses {
    public $storage;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->storage['man'] = new Man();
    }

    public function getClass($name) {
        return $this->storage[$name];
    }
}

function getVal(Man $man) {
    return $man->wife;
}

echo getVal();
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate, I have found a solution