# How can I correctly define a global variable with a query that has global variables in it aswell?

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to do a search function at the moment. I have done it before, but now I have to take the values from a Form in one PHP File and use it in another PHP File.

So I try to save the query in a global variable, but I keep getting errors.

```
"$GLOBALS['searchquery'] = SELECT Titel, Vorname, Nachname, Unternehmen, Gruppe FROM mitglieder WHERE Titel LIKE '%$GLOBALS['searchq']%' OR Vorname LIKE '%$GLOBALS['searchq']%' OR Nachname LIKE '%$GLOBALS['searchq']%' OR Unternehmen LIKE '%$GLOBALS['searchq']%' OR Gruppe LIKE '%$GLOBALS['searchq']%'";
```

If I do it like this it says: Unexpected "

```
$GLOBALS['searchquery'] = "SELECT Titel, Vorname, Nachname, Unternehmen, Gruppe FROM mitglieder WHERE Titel LIKE '".%$GLOBALS['searchq']%."' OR Vorname LIKE '".%$GLOBALS['searchq']%."' OR Nachname LIKE '".%$GLOBALS['searchq']%."' OR Unternehmen LIKE '".%$GLOBALS['searchq']%."' OR Gruppe LIKE '".%$GLOBALS['searchq']%."' ";
```

If I do it like this it says: Unexpected %

```
$GLOBALS['searchquery'] = "SELECT Titel, Vorname, Nachname, Unternehmen, Gruppe FROM mitglieder WHERE Titel LIKE '"%.$GLOBALS['searchq'].%"' OR Vorname LIKE '"%.$GLOBALS['searchq'].%"' OR Nachname LIKE '"%.$GLOBALS['searchq'].%"' OR Unternehmen LIKE '"%.$GLOBALS['searchq'].%"' OR Gruppe LIKE '"%.$GLOBALS['searchq'].%"' ";
```

And If I do it like this it says: Unexpected .

I realize theres alot of similar questions, but I havent found one that uses % so maybe that changes something about how I have to do the query?

Comment: try `'%".$GLOBALS['searchq']."%'`

Comment: Not sure why you are using `$GLOBALS` for this in the first place?

Comment: @NigelRen When I outsourced my dbConnection to a seperate php file I only could use the connect variable when it was defined as a global one. So I assumed that whenever I want to use a variable in another php file it needs to be global? 

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Normally if you want to give access to variables or data in a function, you would pass it as a parameter.  With classes, people tend to have started to use Dependency Injection (DI).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445972/stop-using-global-in-php and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562752/understanding-ioc-containers-and-dependency-injection may be worth a read.

Comment: Thanks! Always happy to improve my code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are putting % in a wrong place.
It should be:

```
$GLOBALS['searchquery'] = "SELECT Titel, Vorname, Nachname, Unternehmen, Gruppe FROM mitglieder WHERE Titel LIKE '%".$GLOBALS['searchq']."%' OR Vorname LIKE '%".$GLOBALS['searchq']."%' OR Nachname LIKE '%".$GLOBALS['searchq']."%' OR Unternehmen LIKE '%".$GLOBALS['searchq']."%' OR Gruppe LIKE '%".$GLOBALS['searchq']."%'";
```